# Force Highcharts to use my min and max

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Getting quite frustrated with highcharts. I have charts with 2 y axes. I want the zeros to be aligned for the chart to make sense. Highcharts doesn't have this functionality out of the box so I've built in my own logic to handle this, which calculates an appropriate min and max for both axes.

I use these calculated values to set `config.yAxis.min` and `config.yAxis.max`. Unfortunately highcharts tries to be smart and re-calculate new min and maxes. This is especially true when I resize the browser window.

I've looked everywhere and can't find a way to forcefully set min and max. Highcharts folks, is there no way to do this? Without this, charts with double axis become completely useless.

Here's a JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/ashokraju/5c676o1j/8

Comment: Could you share a Fiddle please ?

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashokraju/5c676o1j/8/. Please run the app in a new window using the shortcut CTRL + Shift + Enter. You'll notice when you change the width of the window it messes up the alignment of the zeros. Also notice the min, max I set is not being respected.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I've provided a clear question. Why can't I set min and max explicitly on y axes on a charting tool? Seems like a reasonable question...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you use `yAxis.tickPositions` [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions) like that :

```
"yAxis": [{
    "id": "quantity",
    "labels": {},
    "title": {
        "text": "Paying Customers",
        "margin": 25
    },
    "max": 783,
    "min": -401,
    "opposite": false,
    "gridLineColor": "#F7F6FC",
    tickPositions: [-1000, -500, 0, 500, 1000, 1500]
}, {
    "id": "ratio",
    "labels": {
        "format": "{value}%"
    },
    "title": {
        "text": null
    },
    "max": 13450,
    "min": -6725,
    "opposite": true,
    "gridLineColor": "transparent",
    tickPositions: [-10000, -5000, 0, 5000, 10000, 15000]
}]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/5c676o1j/10/)

**Edit :**
*You're calculating the min and max so maybe you will have to calculate the ticks too.*

Comment: Thanks @Core972 but this still isnt' working. Notice how if you run it in a full window (CTRL + SHIFT + Enter) that the one axis changes and the zeros are no longer aligned. I basically need to have highcharts disable this auto adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"max":783,
"min":-401,
"startOnTick": false,
"endOnTick": false,
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick

The tick options force a series to start or end at the specified min/max values.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **zero-align y-axes** Highcharts plugin:

https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/42/Zero-align%20y-axes

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Kamil, but it looks like this is only compatible with "Highcharts 4.1.7 and earlier.". I'm gonna give it a shot, but I"m using highcharts 6.0.4 :S

Comment: It seems that it works with the newest version of Highcharts: https://plnkr.co/edit/Dwnb8f29vKrwT4ulUyCJ?p=preview